# Appropriate statistical test to use

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test, experiment-design, hypothesis-testing

I am running an experiment where I am testing the difference in effectiveness of constructed wetlands. Essentially, I have a control with unplanted wetlands and treatment with planted wetlands and its run over five days. I am testing to see if the nitrogen removed differs between the planted and unplanted.

I have 5 values for the control and 5 for the treatment. I am testing the difference in nitrogen as well as phosphorus concentrations in the water in the planted vs unplanted wetlands over 5 days. I predict that nitrogen and phosphorus content will decrease in the planted wetlands as the plants will use up the nitrogen and phosphorus to survive.

I introduced nitrogen and phosphorus to both systems in the beginning and all other variables were kept constant thereafter. The experiments were run simultaneously, same weather conditions etc.[image]  What test would be best to use on R? I think a repeated measures ANOVA would be the right test to use as the response variable is measured repeatedly over time. Would my assumption be correct?

Comment: You really need to give us more details and context  for us to be able to answer! What is your research hypothesis? Which variable did you measure? ...

Comment: Can you please add this new information to the post as an edit? Not everybody reads comments!

Comment: How does the decrease of nutrient concentrations look like? Would it be possible to fit a simple model (such as an exponential decay model)? Are these wetlands completely independent? Were the experiments conducted simultaneously (and, e.g., subject to the same weather)? Can you provide plots of your data?

Comment: You need to define a hypothesis you'd like to test. E.g., you could be interested in if the nitrogen removed after five days is different between planted and unplanted wetlands. Or you could be interested in if the time courses of nitrogen concentration differ. Depending on the hypothesis, you need different tests. Btw., I find the peak at day 3 interesting. There seems to have been some disturbance that has mobilized or introduced nitrogen.

Comment: yes i am interested in seeing how the nitrogen removal differs after the five days between the planted and unplanted

Comment: OK, that's easy. Calculate the change of concentration for each wetland and (if the distributions of values for each treatment don't look too extreme) do a t-test.

Comment: does taking samples over the 5 day period not affect using the t-test?

Comment: You just stated you are interested in differences after five days. If you are also interested in the period before that, you need a different test. But then you should first state a different hypothesis (or at least research question).